# Make a random line without intersections

Tags: geometry-nodes

Let's say I have a random line generator like this:

[image]

How to make line avoid intersections?

Here is the file to play with: [image]

Comment: Tip: Just don't draw any lines at all. This way you avoid the intersections completely :D No, seriously: You could extrude the edges, and along the edges with their length send a raycast to the extruded object. But the question is: What should happen IF the edges intersect?

Comment: One "easy" way to create a non-intersecting path is by creating a perfect maze. The most efficient path from one point to another is guaranteed to never intersect. I think beginning with a regular 2D grid, displacing the point with a voronoi texture and using the edge paths nodes you can achieve it.

Comment: @Gorgious quite nice idea, but I want to keep random walk style, to keep control over angles.